# Create and write to a database JDBC PySpark

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark

I have a dataframe that I wish to write to a database table, however with the command:

```
df.select("id", "scale", "mentions")\
        .write.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://ec2xxxxamazonaws.com:xxxx/xxxx") \
        .option("dbtable", 'table) \
        .option("user", "xxxx") \
        .option("password", "xxxx") \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver").mode('append').save()
```

I am not able to write to the database because the table already exists since I created it via psql on DB EC2 instance.

My question is, is there a way to create a table, insert queries in the spark python program itself?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can simply use the save mode of ‘append’, in order to insert a data frame into a pre-existing table on PostgreSQL.

Try the below:

```
df.write.format('jdbc').options(
  url='jdbc:postgresql://ec2xxxxamazonaws.com:xxxx/xxxx',
  driver='org.postgresql.Driver',
  dbtable='table',
  user='xxxx',
  password='xxxx').mode('append').save()
```

However, keep in mind this only works if the table has no constraints (I.e. primary key columns or indexes). So generally there are better implementation options for when your table and insert operation contains more complexity. Try this article for a starter: https://medium.com/@radek.strnad/tips-for-using-jdbc-in-apache-spark-sql-396ea7b2e3d3

Comment: Initially what I did was create a table on my database instance and then use spark to insert the dataframe into that table, and that is when I receive this error

Comment: @gammauniversity could you give the schema of your table as it is in PostgreSQL? The documentation gives the above code as a way to insert a data frame to a ore-existing PostgreSQL table.

Comment: table (event int not null, numsources int, nummentions int) this is the schema, the same as my dataframe

Comment: @gammauniversity please post the error message you receive and we’ll proceed from there.